# Accessing dynamic template refs with vue3 and typescript

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

I have a component that dynamically renders components like this:

```
<div class="row" v-for="(formField, index) in form.formFields" :key="index">
  <boolean-form-item
    v-if="formField.fieldType == 'Boolean'"
    v-model="form.formFields[index]"
    :ref="formField.configuration?.key"
  ></boolean-form-item>
  <numeric-form-item
    v-if="formField.fieldType == 'Number'"
    v-model="form.formFields[index]"
    :ref="formField.configuration?.key"
  ></numeric-form-item>
  <dropdown-form-item
    v-if="formField.fieldType == 'Dropdown'"
    v-model="form.formFields[index]"
    :ref="formField.configuration?.key"
  ></dropdown-form-item>
</div>
```

Each of the form-item types have a validate() method that I want to access. The problem is, that when accessing them using the $ref, the type is not known and typescript throws me an error.

```
validate() {
  this.form.formFields.forEach((field) => {
    var key = "";
    if (field.configuration) {
      key = field.configuration.key;
    }

    console.log(this.$refs[key].validate()); // <<--- Error Object is of type 'unknown'
  });
},
```

How can I access the dynamically created children of my component and execute the validate() method?

Comment: Are you sure key is not an empty string, e.g. `field.configuration.key` is not defined? Side note, don't use `var` anymore, in this case `let` would be the correct keyword. Except you are still targeting IE<11 which I wouldn't recommend anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You could use typescript type casting and do something like

```
interface VueFormField extends Vue {
    validate: () => any
}

validate() {
    this.form.formFields.forEach((field) => {
    let key = "";
    if (field.configuration) {
      key = field.configuration.key;
    }
    console.log((this.$refs[key] as VueFormField).validate());
  });
}
```

You could also use the [dynamic component](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-dynamic-async.html#dynamic-async-components) vue feature to get a more elegant solution generating your forms, also using template refs like [this](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api-template-refs.html#usage-inside-v-for)